# How to replace a specific character in a string inside a UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, string, uikit, uitextfield

I have a custom textField's input view - it is a `Numpad` style keyboard. `Numpad` is using to add numbers and math symbols to a `textField`.

I can't figure out how can I change a math symbol in a string if user already add one and wants to change it on another straight away. Here is an example of what I need:

[image]

Here is the code I use:

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

//number formatter
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.locale = .current
formatter.roundingMode = .down

//all possible math operation symbols user can add
let symbolsSet = Set(["+","-","x","/"])
var amountOfSymbols = 0

let numberString = textField.text ?? ""
guard let range = Range(range, in: numberString) else { return false }
let updatedString = numberString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
let correctDecimalString = updatedString.replacingOccurrences(of: formatter.groupingSeparator, with: "")
let completeString = correctDecimalString.replacingOccurrences(of: formatter.decimalSeparator, with: ".")

//current math symbol user add
let symbol = symbolsSet.filter(completeString.contains).last ?? ""
//if user add math symbol to an empty string - do not insert
if string == symbol, numberString.count == 0 { return false }

//count how much math symbols string has. If more that one - do not insert, string can have only one
completeString.forEach { character in
    if symbolsSet.contains(String(character)) {
        amountOfSymbols += 1
    }
}
if amountOfSymbols > 1 { return false }

//count how much decimals string has. If more that one - do not insert because it can have only one per number
let numbersArray = completeString.components(separatedBy: symbol)
for number in numbersArray {
    let amountOfDecimalSigns = number.filter({$0 == "."}).count
    if amountOfDecimalSigns > 1 { return false }
}

//create numbers from a string
guard let firstNumber = Double(String(numbersArray.first ?? "0")) else { return true }
guard let secondNumber = Double(String(numbersArray.last ?? "0")) else { return true }

//format numbers and turn them back to string
let firstFormattedNumber = formatter.string(for: firstNumber) ?? ""
let secondFormattedNumber = formatter.string(for: secondNumber) ?? ""

//assign formatted numbers to a textField
textField.text = completeString.contains(symbol) ? "\(firstFormattedNumber)\(symbol)\(secondFormattedNumber)" : "\(firstFormattedNumber)"

return string == formatter.decimalSeparator
}
```

The logic for me was to use `textField.deleteBackwards()` method to delete an old one and add a new math symbol after, but with above code it doesn't work: it deletes symbol, but a new one doesn't appear - I should press again so new symbol can appear.

What should I do to change a math symbol in a string?

[Test project on GitHub](https://github.com/artexhibit/CustomNumpad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate use a logic as follows.

```
     func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        var shouldChange : Bool = true
        
        //current text visible in the text field
        let numberString = (textField.text ?? "").replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
        
        //last charachter in the text field
        let lastCharachter = numberString.last
        
        //get all the numbers displayed in the textfield by sperating them from symbols
        let numbersArray = numberString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+-x/"))
        
        
        if string == ""{
            
        }
        
        //stop entering a symbol in the first place
        else if numberString == ""{
            if !Character(string).isNumber{
                shouldChange = false
            }
        }
        
        //if a number is entered check for the decimal points
        else if Character(string).isNumber{
            if numbersArray.last!.contains(".") && numbersArray.last?.components(separatedBy: ".").last?.count == 2 && Character(string).isNumber{
                shouldChange =  false
            }else{
                var symbol : String?
                for n in numberString{
                    if "+-/x".contains(n){
                        symbol = String(n)
                        break
                    }
                }
                
                if (symbol != nil){
                    textField.text = "\(numbersArray.first!.withCommas())\(symbol!)\((numbersArray.last! + string).withCommas())"
                }else{
                    textField.text = "\((numbersArray.first! + string).withCommas())"
                }
                shouldChange = false
            }
        // if symbol is entered
        }else{
            if string == "."{
                if !lastCharachter!.isNumber{
                    shouldChange = false
                }
            }

            //if there are more than 1 numbers numbersArray, calculate the value
            else if lastCharachter!.isNumber{
                if numbersArray.count > 1{
                    let expression = NSExpression(format: numberString)
                    let answer =  expression.expressionValue(with:nil, context: nil) as! Double
                    textField.text = "\(forTrailingZero(temp: answer).withCommas())\(string)"
                    shouldChange = false
                }
            }else{
                //change the symbol
                textField.text = "\(textField.text!.dropLast())\(string)"
                shouldChange =  false
            }
        }
        
        return shouldChange
    }

    
    //use to remove trailing zeros
    func forTrailingZero(temp: Double) -> String {
        let tempVar = String(format: "%g", temp)
        return tempVar
    }

extension String {
    func withCommas() -> String {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        numberFormatter.locale = .current
        return numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Double(self)!))!
    }
}
```

There may be different ways of achieving the expected output.

---

This is another way you can achieve the above result.

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
        formatter.locale = .current
        formatter.roundingMode = .down
        
        let numberString = "\(textField.text ?? "")".replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
        let lastCharachter = numberString.last
        
        let numbersArray = numberString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+-x/"))
        
        let amountOfDecimalSigns = "\(numbersArray.last!)\(string)".filter({$0 == "."}).count
        
        if numberString.last == "." && string == "0"{
            formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
        }else{
            formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        }
        
        if string == ""{
            return true
        }

        
        if numberString == ""{
            if Character(string).isNumber{
                textField.text = string
            }else{
                return false
            }
        }
        else if amountOfDecimalSigns > 1{
            return false
        }
        
        else if numbersArray.count > 1 {
            
            var symbol = ""
            for str in numberString{
                if "+-/x".contains(str){
                    symbol = String(str)
                    break
                }
            }
            
            if Character(string).isNumber{
                textField.text = "\(formatter.string(for: Float("\(numbersArray.first!)")! as NSNumber)!)\(symbol)\(formatter.string(for: Float("\(numbersArray.last!)\(string)")! as NSNumber)!)"
            }else if string == "."{
                textField.text = "\(textField.text!)\(string)"
            }
            else{
                if lastCharachter!.isNumber{
                    let expression = NSExpression(format: numberString)
                    let answer =  expression.expressionValue(with:nil, context: nil)
                    textField.text = "\(formatter.string(from: answer as! NSNumber)!)\(string)"
                }else if lastCharachter! == "."{
                    let expression = NSExpression(format: String(numberString.dropLast()))
                    let answer =  expression.expressionValue(with:nil, context: nil)
                    textField.text = "\(formatter.string(from: answer as! NSNumber)!)\(string)"
                }
                else{
                    textField.text = "\(numberString.dropLast())\(string)"
                }

            }
        }else{
            if Character(string).isNumber{
                textField.text = "\(formatter.string(for: Float("\(numbersArray.first!)\(string)")! as NSNumber)!)"
            }else{
                if lastCharachter!.isNumber{
                    textField.text = "\(textField.text!)\(string)"
                }else{
                    textField.text = "\(numberString.dropLast())\(string)"
                }
                    
            }
        }
        
        return false
    }
```

Check the logic in both answers.

Comment: Hi uditha! Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! Can I kindly ask you to check how to format numbers in a textfield, for example `2300499,22 -> 2 300 499,22` or `1235,44+3469,90 -> 1,235,44+3,469,90` (according to user `locale`)? In case with calculation I can format an `answer` constant, but how to deal with dynamically typing numbers in a `textField`? I suppose I should format it and assign to `textField.text` in a part where `number is entered check for the decimal point section`?

Comment: updated the answer. there maybe better ways.

Comment: Dear uditha, thank you very much! I got how to do it. Just a small question which I can't understand: you can't type a number like 12.03. When you type decimal and 0 after - decimal will disappear...

Comment: Dear uditha, thank you! Found some bugs: 1) if you calculate negative value (2-4 = -2), string will be `-2+` and if you press a second number it will crash because `numbersArray.first` will be `nil`, because symbol will be `-` : https://share.cleanshot.com/bA9G9A 2) if you type `1.02` it will format as `1.01`, and `1.01 -> 1`. If you disable formatter rounding mode, then it's ok, but I will be able to change decimal numbers: https://share.cleanshot.com/wTaAfP. How to deal with it?

Comment: check ```numerString.first == "-"```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a listener for your UITextView text change.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: myTextField, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] (notification) in
    guard let self = self else { return }
            
    guard let textField = notification.object as? UITextField else { return }
            
    //here write a logic which verifies if the last character in the text is one of the mathematical symbols, and the one previous to that is also a math symbol, then you would replace the 'lastIndex - 1' with the last character
    guard let text = textField.text, text.count > 2 else { return }
    guard let lastChar = text.last else { return }
    let previousChar: Character = Array(text)[text.count - 2]
    //compare these two characters and make sure the 'previousChar' is a math symbol but not a number, if so - replace it with 'lastChar'
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer. I will try and let you know if it was successful. Could you please check so there is no chance to track it inside `shouldChangeCharactersIn` method in a part where I check for `if amountOfSymbols > 1 { return false }` ? Since the method triggers every time I insert something...

Comment: Technically, you could do the same manipulations to the final string that I described here inside `shouldChangeCharactersIn`. The problem is that when you return `false`, you don't let the textField add the last tapped button. You should always return `true`, but in that case when `if amountOfSymbols > 1` just remove the last character from your total string. P.S: A suggestion: create a `var numberFormatter` in your viewModel or inside your viewController, and just use it inside this delegate method, otherwise it is expensive to always instantiate a new one.

Comment: Hi! I couldn't implement your approach :( I launched a bounty, hope you can try to help me one more time, I would be very grateful. Maybe you can try my test project on GitHub. And maybe my whole approach was wrong, that is why I can't do that in borders of shouldChangeCharactersIn? I also updated the initial post with a closest working solution, but it's not ideal...

Comment: This line is wrong:
`completeString.removeAll { symbolsSet.contains(String($0))}`. Obviously it will remove all the symbols in the string. You want to remove just the last character in the string. Also, can you show an image of the actual thing you want to build? Do you want to just continuously write in one line `54+3-22+45/5%13+27`? Like that? Why not perform the math calculation when you have `a digit` - then a `math sign` - and when the `next digit` is written the app would show the result? Otherwise, you will have a hell when trying to calculate the whole string.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I got it wrong, but thought maybe I can add a condition where it shouldn't delete all symbols if I press on math symbol again. Not like you show. I want: 1,58+1 max in string (2 numbers and I math sign, he can't type 1,58+1-3x4). If user have 1,58+ and press on another math sign - it should change 1.58- or 1.58x. If user have 1,58+1 and presses = show calc result, if he presses another math sign then calc, show result and a math sign he pressed (1,58+1, user press -, string shows 2,58-) and user can type second number again.  1/2

Comment: Important: all numbers should be formatted with decimal and grouping separator according to locale (implemented). Here is a GIF with behaviour (but without formatting): https://share.cleanshot.com/nXOIID 2/2

Comment: I am at work now, and can't write an answer now. I will get back home in the evening and I will write a working example, if nobody else will be quicker.

Comment: Sure, thank you one more time for the help. I am new to swift and work on my first app, and I didn't find any similar tutorial, which explains of how to implement that.